# Is there an R package with a pretty function that can deal effectively with outliers?

Tags: r, outliers, missing-data

One of the data sets I deal with is quite strange. The datawarehouse I downloaded the data from has a lot 999999999 values in one of the variables. Apparently the computer system on which the datawarehouse sits on does not support storing of null values. So they use 999999999 as the "null" value. Now if I just run `pretty` in R on the variable, it gives non-sensical ranges.

- Is there a package with a version of `pretty` that can deal with outliers by putting them in the range of say (100,High) ?

Comment: Why not just remove the 999999999 values?

Comment: or mark them as `NA`: `foo[foo == 999999999] <- NA`

Comment: I can't remove them as there are 1000 variables in the dataset and it's difficult to know which variables has which default value. Also if confronted by a new dataset the same has to be done. Sometimes the default value is 99999990 for example. So it's better to have a general algorithm that can deal with that

Answer (score 18):

If you're importing your data with a command like, say,

```
read.table('yourfile.txt', header=TRUE, ...)
```

you can indicate what values are to be considered as "null" or `NA` values, by specifying `na.strings = "999999999"`. We can also consider different values for indicating `NA` values. Consider the following file (`fake.txt`) where we want to treat "." and "999999999" as NA values:

```
1 2 .
3 999999999 4
5 6 7
```

then in R we would do:

```
> a <- read.table("fake.txt", na.strings=c(".","999999999"))
> a
  V1 V2 V3
1  1  2 NA
2  3 NA  4
3  5  6  7
```

Otherwise, you can always filter your data as indicated by @Sacha in his comment. Here, it could be something like

```
a[a=="." | a==999999999] <- NA
```

**Edit**

In case there are multiple abnormal values that can possibly be observed in different columns with different values, *but you know the likely range of admissible values*, you can apply a function to each column. For example, define the following filter:

```
my.filter <- function(x, threshold=100) ifelse(x > threshold, NA, x)
```

then

```
a.filt <- apply(a, 2, my.filter)
```

will replace every value > 100 with NA in the matrix `a`.

*Example:*

```
> a <- replicate(10, rnorm(10))
> a[1,3] <- 99999999
> a[5,6] <- 99999999
> a[8,10] <- 99999990
> summary(a[,3])
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 -1e+00   0e+00   0e+00   1e+07   1e+00   1e+08 
> af <- apply(a, 2, my.filter)
> summary(af[,3])
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
-1.4640 -0.2680  0.4671 -0.0418  0.4981  0.7444  1.0000
```

It can be vector-based of course:

```
> summary(my.filter(a[,3], 500))
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
-1.4640 -0.2680  0.4671 -0.0418  0.4981  0.7444  1.0000
```

Comment: You don't always know in advance what the special values are, especially if you are seeing the dataset for the first time! I was hoping there would be a cut2 or something function that deals with that already.

Comment: @xiaodai Yes there is a `cut()` function in R but it does probably not do what you want. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I encounter this quite frequently when dealing with customer daily time series data. It appears that many accounting systems IGNORE daily data that didn't occur i.e. no transactions were recorded for that day (time interval/bucket) and don't fill in a '0" number . Since time series analysis require a reading for every interval/bucket we need to inject a "0" for the omitted observation. Intervention Detection is essentially a scheme to detect the anomaly and replace it with an expected value based on an identified profile/signal/prediction. If there are many of these 'missing values" the system can break down The problem becomes a little more complex when there is strong day-of-the-week profile in the historical data and a "sequential patch of values" are not recorded, suggesting that replacement values be obtained by computing local daily averages as a precursor to fine-tuning these values.